# IE8 does not support italic tags in extjs4

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs3

I am trying to make my font italic. It works fine in all browsers except for IE8.
 Is there a fix for this issue?
Here is the jsfddle:

```
            {
                xtype: 'text',
                padding: '64 0 0 0',    
                text: "Logged in as:",
                textAlign:'left',
                style : "color:#3E546B;font-style:italic;font-size: 11px;",
                width: 140
            }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YeyET/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you really need is no a text but a displayfield instead.

This works ok in IE, Chrome and FF:

```
{
    xtype: 'displayfield',
    padding: '64 0 0 0', 
    fieldLabel:  'Logged in as:',                  
    value: 'Lucas',
    textAlign:'left',
    labelCls: 'ital',
    width: 140
}
```

Take a look at how it looks in jsfiddle.net: http://jsfiddle.net/lontivero/YeyET/6/